# Eval in PHP and security measures , Creating a PHP demo editor

Tags: php, security, eval, user-input

I know that eval is the function in PHP to execute PHP code from an input. Now I want to make a W3Schools like editor. What can I do to protect eval code that I get from POST variable.

```
$code = eval($_POST["phpusercode"]);
echo $code;
```

What I want to do is when a user will make a function like this

I want to give user the ability to write his own PHP code on my site without making my website vulnerable to some sort of hacking.

Comment: `to display` -- no. `to execute` -- yes

Comment: You can ask the people of http://writecodeonline.com/php/ how they did it perhaps, this discussion would lead way too far considering all the involved security risks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) evaluates code, so, as @sectus says in comments, execute the code

For example:

```
eval ("echo 'Hello user'"); //This will execute echo 'Hello user'
```

So, in your case i think you don't want to execute your user code, so please carify your question and update it.

IMPORTANT:

- Use of `eval` is highly discouraged
- NEVER EVER use `eval` with params by `POST/GET` without sanitize them

Useful links:

[When eval is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php)

[Avoid SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: Just for quick reminder; POST and GET are not only user controlled variables. You should check out COOKIE and all other http header parameters.